# How to Acces a Wrappedarray from Dataframe's Map

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, udf

I have a Dataframe like this:

```
    +------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|myKeys|myMaps                                                                        |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|b     |Map(b -> WrappedArray([1,o], [4,xxx]), a -> WrappedArray([1,o], [1,n], [1,n]))|
|a     |Map(b -> WrappedArray([1,o], [4,n]), a -> WrappedArray([4,c], [1,n], [1,n]))  |
|a     |Map(b -> WrappedArray([4,o], [3,n]), a -> WrappedArray([4,o], [1,n], [1,n]))  |
|b     |Map(b -> WrappedArray([4,a], [3,n]), a -> WrappedArray([1,o], [1,n], [1,n]))  |
+------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

With this schema

```
    root
 |-- myKeys: string (nullable = false)
 |-- myMaps: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

Here is the code to create it:

```
val x = sc.parallelize(Seq(
      Array(("a", "1", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "1", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "4", "xxx")),
      Array(("a", "1", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "1", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "4", "n")),
      Array(("a", "1", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "4", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "3", "n")),
      Array(("a", "1", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "4", "o"), ("a", "1", "n"), ("b", "3", "n"))
    )).map(x => testSchema(x)).toDF("myArrays")


val y = x.withColumn("myKeys", lit("b"))

val getMap = udf((mouvements: mutable.WrappedArray[Row]) => {
  val test = mouvements.toArray
    .map(line => (line(0).toString, line(1).toString, line(2).toString))
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map{case (k,values) => k -> values.map(x => (x._2, x._3))}
  test})


val df_with_map = y.select($"myKeys", getMap($"myArrays") as "myMaps")
df_with_map show false
df_with_map printSchema
```

Now, I would like to access the second element of my array wich have the first element equals to 4 and the key of the map equlas to b. I should have a result like this

```
+---+
|val|
+---+
|xxx|
|c  |
|o  |
|a  |
+---+
```

I already try this doing it with this udf:

```
val getMyValue = udf{(myKey: String, myMaps:  Map[String, WrappedArray[Row]]) =>

  val first_val= "4"
  val myArrays = myMaps.get(myKey)
  val res = myArrays.get.toArray.filter{x => x.getString(0) == first_val}
  res
}

val df_value = df_with_map.select(getMyValue($"myKey",$"myMaps") as "myValue")
df_value show false
df_value printSchema
```

But it return the error

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Schema for type org.apache.spark.sql.Row is not supported
```

one the line:

```
 val getMyValue = udf{(myKey: String, myMaps:  Map[String, WrappedArray[Row]]) =>
```

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
val first_val = "4"
val df = Seq(
  ("b", Map("b" -> Seq(("1", "o"), ("4", "xxx"))))
).toDF("myKeys", "myMaps")

root
 |-- myKeys: string (nullable = true)
 |-- myMaps: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: string
 |    |-- value: array (valueContainsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

```
df.select($"myMaps".getItem("b"))
  .as[Seq[(String, String)]]
  .flatMap(xs => xs.filter(_._1 == first_val).map(_._2))
```

*Edit*:

```
df.as[(String, Map[String,Seq[(String, String)]])].flatMap {
  case (key, map) => 
    map.getOrElse(key, Seq[(String, String)]()).filter(_._1 == first_val).map(_._2)
}
```

Comment: Nice It work but I think my example was too simple. The problem I have is that the key I want to get value from is not knowed before the select so I cant call the getItem method. I will redit the question to make it more exhaustive

Comment: I update my post to give a better explanationof  my problem

Comment: When I want to call your method on my DataFrame It return :
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'cast(myKeys as map<string,array<struct<_1:string,_2:string>>>)' due to data type mismatch: cannot cast StringType to MapType(StringType,ArrayType(StructType(StructField(_1,StringType,true), StructField(_2,StringType,true)),true),true);
So It work for your example but not for mine.

Comment: thank for your answers but despite this is the same schema, when you call getItem method your directly give the key "b". I need to get the key from the column myKeys of the dataFrame. From the first line I need to getItem for key "b" but for the second line, I need to getItem for key "a". Any Idea?